# Implicit conversion not happening in class templates

Tags: c++, c++17

I am writing a simple std::array based string class as follows. The class is expected to behave like std::string in a very limited way, but with all data stored on stack. Also it has few constructors to construct from const char* and std::string. Below is the code:

```
#ifndef SSTRING_H
#define SSTRING_H

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstring>
#include <iterator>
#include <ostream>


// friend operator declarations
template <typename CharT, std::size_t SizeT>
class basic_sstring;
template <typename CharT, std::size_t SizeT>
constexpr bool operator == (const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>&, const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>&);
template <typename CharT, std::size_t SizeT>
constexpr bool operator != (const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>&, const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>&);
template <typename CharT, std::size_t SizeT>
constexpr basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT> operator + (const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>&,
                                                  const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>&);
template <typename CharT, std::size_t SizeT>
std::basic_ostream<CharT>& operator << (std::basic_ostream<CharT>&, const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>&);


// basic_sstring class template
template <typename CharT, std::size_t SizeT = 512>
class basic_sstring
{
public:
    typedef CharT value_type;

    // constructor for empty basic_sstring
    constexpr basic_sstring() : _size(0) 
    {
        _data[_size] = static_cast<CharT>(0);
    }

    // constructor for const char* with a size specified
    constexpr basic_sstring(const CharT* data_, std::size_t size_)
        : _size(size_)
    {
        std::memcpy(&_data[0], data_, _size*sizeof(CharT));
        _data[_size] = static_cast<CharT>(0);
    }

     // constructor for const char* which is null terminated
    constexpr basic_sstring(const CharT* data_)
        : _size(std::char_traits<CharT>::length(data_))
    {
        std::memcpy(&_data[0], data_, _size*sizeof(CharT));
        _data[_size] = static_cast<CharT>(0);
    }

    // constructor for std::string
    constexpr basic_sstring(const std::basic_string<CharT>& str_)
        : _size(str_.size())
    {
        std::memcpy(&_data[0], str_.c_str(), _size*sizeof(CharT));
        _data[_size] = static_cast<CharT>(0);
    }

    // default copy constructor
    // default move constructor

    // operators

    // default copy assigment operator
    // default move assigment operator

    // comparison operators
    constexpr friend bool operator == <> (const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>&, const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>&);
    constexpr friend bool operator != <>(const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>&, const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>&);

    // + operator
    constexpr friend basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT> operator + <> (const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>&,
                                                                const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>&);

    // += operator
    constexpr basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT> operator += (const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>& other_)
    {
        return *this + other_;
    }

    // << operator
    friend std::basic_ostream<CharT>& operator << <> (std::basic_ostream<CharT>&,
                                                      const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>&);

    // reference to internal buffer
    constexpr const CharT* data() const { return &_data[0]; };

    // capacity
    constexpr std::size_t capacity() { return SizeT; }

    // size
    constexpr std::size_t size() { return _size; };

private:

    std::array<CharT, SizeT>        _data;
    std::size_t                    _size;
};

// == operator for basic_sstring
template <typename CharT, std::size_t SizeT>
constexpr bool operator == (const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>& first_,
                            const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>& second_)
{
    return first_._size == second_._size && first_._data == second_._data;
}

// != operator for basic_sstring
template <typename CharT, std::size_t SizeT>
constexpr bool operator != (const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>& first_,
                            const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>& second_)
{
    return !(first_ == second_);
}

// + operator for basic_sstring
template <typename CharT, std::size_t SizeT>
constexpr basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT> operator + (const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>& first_,
                                                  const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>& second_)
{
    auto result = first_;
    std::memcpy(&result._data[result._size], &second_._data[0], second_._size*sizeof(CharT));
    result._size += second_._size;
    result._data[result._size] = static_cast<CharT>(0);

    return result;
}

// << operator for basic_sstring
template <typename CharT, std::size_t SizeT>
std::basic_ostream<CharT>& operator << (std::basic_ostream<CharT>& out,
                                        const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>& sstr_)
{
    std::copy(sstr_._data.begin(), sstr_._data.begin() + sstr_._size, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(out));
    return out;
}

typedef basic_sstring<char> sstring;

#endif
```

But for some reason, implicit conversions from std::string and const char* doesn't seem to be happening when i use it. I am using the below code to run it. Any ideas.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "SString.h"

int main()
{
    sstring a = "First";
    sstring b = a + " Second";
    sstring c = a + b + " Third";

    std::cout << "A = " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "B = " << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "C = " << c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

So I followed the method described by r3mus n0x below (along with few other changes that led from it like having to define friend functions within the class itself). I had a few more errors in the code. After clearing them it works fine. Adding the working sstring code and test code below for reference.

```
#ifndef SSTRING_H
#define SSTRING_H

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstring>
#include <iterator>
#include <ostream>
#include <type_traits>


// friend operator declarations
template <typename CharT, std::size_t SizeN>
class basic_sstring;

template <typename CharT, std::size_t SizeN>
std::basic_ostream<CharT>& operator << (std::basic_ostream<CharT>&, const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeN>&);


// basic_sstring class template
template <typename CharT, std::size_t SizeN = 512>
class basic_sstring
{
public:
    typedef CharT value_type;

    // constructor for empty basic_sstring
    constexpr basic_sstring() : _size(0) 
    {
        _data[_size] = static_cast<CharT>(0);
    }

    // constructor for const char* with a size specified
    constexpr basic_sstring(const CharT* data_, std::size_t size_)
        : _size(size_)
    {
        std::memcpy(&_data[0], data_, _size*sizeof(CharT));
        _data[_size] = static_cast<CharT>(0);
    }

     // constructor for const char* which is null terminated
    constexpr basic_sstring(const CharT* data_)
        : _size(std::char_traits<CharT>::length(data_))
    {
        std::memcpy(&_data[0], data_, _size*sizeof(CharT));
        _data[_size] = static_cast<CharT>(0);
    }

    // constructor for std::string
    constexpr basic_sstring(const std::basic_string<CharT>& str_)
        : _size(str_.size())
    {
        std::memcpy(&_data[0], str_.c_str(), _size*sizeof(CharT));
        _data[_size] = static_cast<CharT>(0);
    }

    // default copy constructor
    // default move constructor

    // operators

    // default copy assigment operator
    // default move assigment operator

    // == operator
    template <typename T1, typename T2,
        typename String1 = decltype(basic_sstring(std::declval<T1>())),
        typename String2 = decltype(basic_sstring(std::declval<T2>()))>
    constexpr friend bool operator==(const T1 & first_, const T2 & second_)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<String1, String2>::value, "Incompatable type used to compare with sstring");
        auto first = String1(first_);
        auto second = String2(second_);
        return (first._size == second._size) && 
            (std::equal(first._data.begin(), first._data.begin() + first._size, second._data.begin()));
    }

    // != operator
    template <typename T1, typename T2,
        typename String1 = decltype(basic_sstring(std::declval<T1>())),
        typename String2 = decltype(basic_sstring(std::declval<T2>()))>
    constexpr friend bool operator != (const T1 & first_, const T2 & second_)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<String1, String2>::value, "Incompatable type used to compare with sstring");
        return !(first_ == second_);
    }

    // + operator
    template <typename T1, typename T2,
        typename String1 = decltype(basic_sstring(std::declval<T1>())),
        typename String2 = decltype(basic_sstring(std::declval<T2>()))>
    constexpr friend String1 operator + (const T1 & first_, const T2 & second_)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<String1, String2>::value, "Incompatable type used to add with sstring");
        auto result = String1(first_);
        auto second = String2(second_);
        std::memcpy(&result._data[result._size], &second._data[0], second._size*sizeof(typename String1::value_type));
        result._size += second._size;
        result._data[result._size] = static_cast<typename String1::value_type>(0);

        return result;
    }

    // += operator
    template <typename T, typename String = decltype(basic_sstring(std::declval<T>()))>
    constexpr basic_sstring<CharT, SizeN>& operator += (const T& other_)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<String, basic_sstring<CharT, SizeN> >::value,
                                             "Incompatable type used to add with sstring");
        auto other = String(other_);
        std::memcpy(&_data[_size], &other._data[0], other._size*sizeof(typename String::value_type));
        _size += other._size;
        _data[_size] = static_cast<typename String::value_type>(0);
        return *this;
    }

    // << operator
    friend std::basic_ostream<CharT>& operator << <> (std::basic_ostream<CharT>&,
                                                      const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeN>&);

    // reference to internal buffer
    constexpr const CharT* data() const { return &_data[0]; };

    // capacity
    constexpr std::size_t capacity() const { return SizeN; }

    // size
    constexpr std::size_t size() const { return _size; };

    // clear
    constexpr void clear() { _size = 0; }

    // empty
    constexpr bool empty() const { return 0 == _size; }

    // underlying array const
    constexpr const std::array<CharT, SizeN>&  underlying_array() const { return _data; }

    // underlying array non const
    constexpr std::array<CharT, SizeN>&  underlying_array() { return _data; }

private:

    std::array<CharT, SizeN>        _data;
    std::size_t                     _size;
};

// << operator for basic_sstring
template <typename CharT, std::size_t SizeN>
std::basic_ostream<CharT>& operator << (std::basic_ostream<CharT>& out,
                                        const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeN>& sstr_)
{
    std::copy(sstr_._data.begin(), sstr_._data.begin() + sstr_._size, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(out));
    return out;
}

// User-defined deduction guides
template <typename CharT>
basic_sstring(const std::basic_string<CharT>&) -> basic_sstring<CharT, 512>;
template <typename CharT>
basic_sstring(const CharT*) -> basic_sstring<CharT, 512>;


typedef basic_sstring<char> sstring;

#endif
```

Tested it using below code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "SString.h"

int main()
{
    // Testing constructors and addition operators
    sstring a = " First ";
    sstring b = a + std::string(" Second ");
    sstring c = a + b + " Third ";
    c += c;

    std::cout << "A = " << a << std::endl; //  First
    std::cout << "B = " << b << std::endl; //  First  Second 
    std::cout << "C = " << c << std::endl; //  First  First  Second  Third  First  First  Second  Third 

    // Testing comparison operators
    sstring d = " Fourth ";
    std::cout << "Comparison 1: " << (d == " Fourth ") << std::endl; // 1
    std::cout << "Comparison 2: " << (d == std::string(" Fourth ")) << std::endl; // 1
    std::cout << "Comparison 3: " << (d == sstring(" Fourth ")) << std::endl; // 1
    std::cout << "Comparison 4: " << (d == sstring(" Fifth ")) << std::endl; // 0
    std::cout << "Comparison 5: " << (d != " Fifth ") << std::endl; // 1
    std::cout << "Comparison 6: " << (d != std::string(" Fifth ")) << std::endl; // 1
    std::cout << "Comparison 7: " << (d != sstring(" Fifth ")) << std::endl; // 1
    std::cout << "Comparison 8: " << (d != sstring(" Fourth ")) << std::endl; // 0
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very frustrating thing that I've battled with as well. You'll have to try a [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)-based approach instead:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2,
    typename String1 = decltype(basic_sstring(std::declval<T1>())),
    typename String2 = decltype(basic_sstring(std::declval<T2>()))>
constexpr bool operator==(const T1 &string1, const T2 &string2);
```

It uses [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) so you might need to add a user-defined deduction guide for your basic_string-based constructor:

```
template <typename CharT>
basic_sstring(const std::basic_string<CharT>&) -> basic_sstring<CharT, 512>;
```

Comment: I find this very interesting (I'm rather new to all this).  Do you have time to put up a minimal live demo at (say) [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/)?

Comment: @PaulSanders, sorry, I don't. But if you are going to try this approach yourself and run into some trouble, please don't hesitate to ask for clarification.

Comment: OK, might try, depending.  Thanks.

Comment: @r3mus n0x Thanks..it works fine now. Only issue being that sstring creates extra copies of the arguments within the definition of each operator. But since there is no heap allocation that is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Template deduction happens before overload resolution and any possible conversion for parameters. So your operator:

```
basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT> operator + (const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>& first_,
                                        const basic_sstring<CharT, SizeT>& second_)
```

just isn't considered, unless the compiler can deduce `CharT` and `SizeT` for *both* parameters. And of course it cannot when one parameter is a literal.

The "real" `std::string` has [a dozen overloads of `operator+`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) to overcome this.

Comment: So that means i need to create overloads for whichever conversion i need like say const char* and std::string? Any other method available to resolve it? Also i suppose this need to be done for all operators that are required?

Comment: In principle, yes. The problem is that the compiler first collects possible overloads, and only *then* considers any conversions for the parameters. Templates would be discarded already in the first round, if the template parameters cannot be deduced.